# Check that I didn't misuse the triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis

This is a proof I am working on, and I think I've got it, but I wanted to make sure I didn't misuse the triangle inequality. I will point out what steps I think I may have made an implicit assumption.

### Problem

Let $\vec{u} \in R^n$ be a vector such that $\|\vec{u}\| < 1$. Prove that if $\vec{v}$ is a vector in $R^n$ such that $\|\vec{v}-\vec{u}\| < 1-\|\vec{u}\|$, then $\|\vec{v}\| < 1$.

### proof

We start by adding and subtracting the point 0. So we have the quantity written as $\|(v - 0) +( 0 - u)\|$.
Using the triangle inequality we have

$\|(v - 0) +( 0 - u)\| \leq \| v - 0\| +\|0 - u\| \leq \|v\| + \|u\|$

By our estimate that $\|v - u \| \leq 1 - \|u\|$, we have

$$\|v\| + \|u\| \leq 1 - \|u\|$$
$$\|v\| \leq 1 - 2\|u\|$$

And since $\|u\| < 1$, $1 - 2\|u\| < 1$, so it follows that $$\|v\| < 1$$.

### comments

I wasn't really sure if adding and subtracting $0$ to the original quantitiy was allowed, it seems like a dirty trick that makes the rest follow too easily. But I don't think I did anything wrong.

Comment: Given $\lVert v-u\rVert \leq 1-\lVert u\rVert$ and $\lVert v-u\rVert \leq \lVert v\rVert+\lVert u \rVert$, you cannot just say $\lVert v\rVert +\lVert u \rVert\leq 1-\lVert u\rVert$.  There's nothing wrong with adding and subtracting zero, your error is in assuming that somehow $x\leq y$ and $x\leq z$ implies $y\leq z$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I definitely overlooked that, I'm very inexperienced with inequalities, could you offer a hint to maybe help me connect those two things together? Or is this approach I'm taking probably not the best?

Comment: I highly recommend using the *reverse* triangle inequality, which follows from the triangle inequality  I.e., $\left| \lVert x\rVert - \lVert y\rVert \right|\leq \lVert x-y\rVert$.  I think you'll find it quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's take a look at $\mathbb{R}^1$, consider $v = u = \frac{1}{2}$, then we have $\lvert v - u \rvert = 0 < \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \lvert u \rvert$ but $\lvert v \rvert + \lvert u \rvert = 1 \not< \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \lvert u \rvert$ so that inequality you use is incorrect.